# GCMRegistrat.getRegistrationId(this) gives back an empty string

Tags: registration, google-cloud-messaging

I know there are a lot of simular questions on the net about this topic but I kinda feel like I do everything everybody is saying. When I say

```
final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
```

it is giving back an amty string. But later on in my LogCat it states that the device is registered with indeed a regId.

Here's my code:

PushAndroidActivity.java

```
package com.w.v;

import static com.w.v.CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.w.v.ServerUtilities;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

public class PushAndroidActivity extends Activity {

private String TAG = "** pushAndroidActivity **";
private TextView mDisplay;
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    checkNotNull(SENDER_ID, "SENDER_ID");

    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);


    Intent i = getIntent();
    String name         = i.getStringExtra("namepass");
    String email        = i.getStringExtra("emailpass");
    String password     = i.getStringExtra("passwordpass");
    String id           = i.getStringExtra("idpass");


    //setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);

        final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
            Log.i(TAG, "registration id =====  "+regId);

            if (regId.equals("")) {
                GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("SENDER_ID =",SENDER_ID);
            } else {
                // Device is already registered on GCM
                if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
                    // Skips registration.              
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
                    // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
                    // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
                    final Context context = this;
                    mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                        @Override
                        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                            // Register on our server
                            // On server creates a new user

                            Intent i = getIntent();
                            String name         = i.getStringExtra("namepass");
                            String email        = i.getStringExtra("emailpass");
                            String password     = i.getStringExtra("passwordpass");
                            String id           = i.getStringExtra("idpass");

                            ServerUtilities.register(context, name, email, regId);

                            Log.d("name",name);
                            Log.d("email",email);
                            Log.d("regId",regId);

                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                            mRegisterTask = null;
                        }

                    };
                    mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
                }
            }

            Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WebViewActivity.class);
                dashboard.putExtra("namepass", name);
                dashboard.putExtra("emailpass", email);
                dashboard.putExtra("passwordpass", password);
                dashboard.putExtra("idpass", id);
                dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(dashboard);

            //mDisplay.setText("ffffff        "+regId);
        }

    private void checkNotNull(Object reference, String name) {
        if (reference == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException(getString(R.string.error_config, name));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        GCMRegistrar.unregister(this);
    }
}
```

GCMIntentService.java

```
package com.w.v;

import static com.w.v.CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService{

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(SENDER_ID);
    }

    private static final String TAG = "===GCMIntentService===";


    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context arg0, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
    }

    @Override
        protected void onUnregistered(Context arg0, String arg1) {
        Log.i(TAG, "unregistered = "+arg1);
    }

    @Override
        protected void onMessage(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        Log.i(TAG, "new message= ");
    }

    @Override
        protected void onError(Context arg0, String errorId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
    }

    @Override
        protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }
}
```

LogCat when running app in android 4.2.2

```
03-07 09:39:29.001: W/Bundle(20972): Key idpass expected String but value was a java.lang.Integer.  The default value <null> was returned.
03-07 09:39:29.001: W/Bundle(20972): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
03-07 09:39:29.001: W/Bundle(20972): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
03-07 09:39:29.001: W/Bundle(20972):    at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1069)
03-07 09:39:29.001: W/Bundle(20972):    at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:4302)
03-07 09:39:29.001: W/Bundle(20972):    at com.w.v.PushAndroidActivity.onCreate(PushAndroidActivity.java:36)
03-07 09:39:29.001: W/Bundle(20972):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
03-07 09:39:29.001: W/Bundle(20972):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
03-07 09:39:29.001: W/Bundle(20972):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
03-07 09:39:29.001: W/Bundle(20972):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-07 09:39:29.001: W/Bundle(20972):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-07 09:39:29.001: W/Bundle(20972):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-07 09:39:29.001: W/Bundle(20972):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-07 09:39:29.001: W/Bundle(20972):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-07 09:39:29.001: W/Bundle(20972):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-07 09:39:29.001: W/Bundle(20972):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-07 09:39:29.001: W/Bundle(20972):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-07 09:39:29.001: W/Bundle(20972):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-07 09:39:29.001: W/Bundle(20972):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-07 09:39:29.001: W/Bundle(20972):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-07 09:39:29.001: I/** pushAndroidActivity **(20972): registration id =====  
03-07 09:39:29.001: D/GCMRegistrar(20972): resetting backoff for com.w.v
03-07 09:39:29.001: V/GCMRegistrar(20972): Registering app com.w.v of senders 611573915552
03-07 09:39:29.016: D/SENDER_ID =(20972): 611573915552
03-07 09:39:29.040: D/GCMRegistrar(20972): resetting backoff for com.w.v
03-07 09:39:29.040: V/GCMRegistrar(20972): Unregistering app com.w.v
03-07 09:39:29.079: D/dalvikvm(20972): GC_CONCURRENT freed 579K, 6% free 11104K/11712K, paused 4ms+4ms, total 45ms
03-07 09:39:29.133: D/webviewglue(20972): nativeDestroy view: 0x5cf71940
03-07 09:39:29.211: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(20972): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
03-07 09:39:29.211: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(20972): GCM IntentService class: com.w.v.GCMIntentService
03-07 09:39:29.211: V/GCMBaseIntentService(20972): Acquiring wakelock
03-07 09:39:29.297: V/GCMBaseIntentService(20972): Intent service name: GCMIntentService-611573915552-5
03-07 09:39:29.297: D/GCMBaseIntentService(20972): handleRegistration: registrationId = APA91bFJW_CNYh5AYKomkUPvVGvQay0WgL_GH8DdoxooBXcJSo1ryONrB4VcsRysYedx-oKjgDiPSzhrXR6s8HBH7pIl47SvYR5chuJtJWlymZVRm8j7E77F3TirMqF3ag5D8lbOScTVzzA6ZqWMhTDdiAYPkYc5Hw, error = null, unregistered = null
03-07 09:39:29.297: D/GCMRegistrar(20972): resetting backoff for com.w.v
03-07 09:39:29.297: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(20972): onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
03-07 09:39:29.297: V/GCMBroadcastReceiver(20972): GCM IntentService class: com.w.v.GCMIntentService
03-07 09:39:29.297: V/GCMBaseIntentService(20972): Acquiring wakelock
03-07 09:39:29.297: V/GCMRegistrar(20972): Saving regId on app version 2
03-07 09:39:29.321: I/===GCMIntentService===(20972): Device registered: regId = APA91bFJW_CNYh5AYKomkUPvVGvQay0WgL_GH8DdoxooBXcJSo1ryONrB4VcsRysYedx-oKjgDiPSzhrXR6s8HBH7pIl47SvYR5chuJtJWlymZVRm8j7E77F3TirMqF3ag5D8lbOScTVzzA6ZqWMhTDdiAYPkYc5Hw
03-07 09:39:29.321: V/GCMBaseIntentService(20972): Releasing wakelock
03-07 09:39:29.329: D/GCMBaseIntentService(20972): handleRegistration: registrationId = null, error = null, unregistered = com.w.v
03-07 09:39:29.329: D/GCMRegistrar(20972): resetting backoff for com.w.v
03-07 09:39:29.329: V/GCMRegistrar(20972): Saving regId on app version 2
03-07 09:39:29.344: I/===GCMIntentService===(20972): unregistered = APA91bFJW_CNYh5AYKomkUPvVGvQay0WgL_GH8DdoxooBXcJSo1ryONrB4VcsRysYedx-oKjgDiPSzhrXR6s8HBH7pIl47SvYR5chuJtJWlymZVRm8j7E77F3TirMqF3ag5D8lbOScTVzzA6ZqWMhTDdiAYPkYc5Hw
03-07 09:39:29.344: V/GCMBaseIntentService(20972): Releasing wakelock
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.w.v"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <permission android:name="com.w.v.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.w.v.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/v_icon_72_72"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >

        <activity android:name=".OpenApp" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.w.v.LoginActivity" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".WebViewActivity"
            android:label="WebView" 
            android:noHistory="true">
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".PushAndroidActivity"
            android:label="PushAndroid" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.w.v" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

I build this app with help of [this](http://fundroiding.wordpress.com/2012/06/29/google-cloud-messaging-for-android-gcm-simple-tutorial/) tutorial

Any help will be appreciated!! Tnx in advance!

PS: I know there's some code in here which I dont use at the moment.. Its there for future purposes

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem, the first time you attempt to get the registration ID it will be blank, you need to register with GCM in order to get that value. It is returned from their servers. After you have registered (GCMIntentService.onRegistered() is called and your regID is given to your), GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this); will return your string. So the next time you run your app you should get the string. Also I don't think you mean to unregister in onPause(). And you should fix the exception.

Comment: @ Selsine.. Thank you for your answer. When I install de app it toasts "registered with GCM" which looks oke since you have to rigister. But when I then logout and login again it toasts the same thing. And the LogCat states as shown in my question. LogCat says 03-07 09:39:29.001: I/** pushAndroidActivity **(20972): registration id =====   after the ===== its states  string regId which is emty at that moment. Even when I login several times. I cant find what I am doing wrong. Been searching the web for days now :(

Comment: That is because you are unregistering with GCM in onPause() by calling: GCMRegistrar.unregister(this); You don't need to unregister with GCM like that.

Comment: @ Selsine.. Thank you very much!! That seems to solve a lot of problems.. Now I have other errors which I have to solve, but I wont bother you with that before I try and solve it myself. What I do want to ask you is how should I unregister if noy in onpause.. ? tnx in advance!

Comment: You should do it from a preference perhaps, or let it happen automatically as described here: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#unreg

Comment: @ Selsine.. Thank you again.. I will look into this. Tnx again! You've been a great help.

Comment: No problem, good luck with your app!